# Data binding doesn't work for Image UriSource

Tags: wpf

I have a image in window

```
  <Image   Source="{Binding Path=MYImage, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=imageConverter}}" />
```

I have also tried using a value converter:

```
 public  class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            return new BitmapImage(new Uri((string)value));
        }
        catch
        {
            return new BitmapImage();
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
                              object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and created a dependency property for it.

```
 public string MYImage
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MYImageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MYImageProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MYImageProperty=DependencyProperty.Register("PickerImage",typeof(string),typeof(MYClass),new PropertyMetadata("/MYProject;component/pic.png"));
```

but when i use it, don't show image !!!

Comment: have you tried relative path in MyImage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't have to convert the source.

you can Bind a string like that:

```
"/My.Namespace;component/Resources/thatsMyImage.png"
```

xaml:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=MYImage}" />
```

Comment: What says the output window in Visual Studio?

Comment: Set value for MYImage but don't show. when i use this string for text of textblock don't show text for textblock :(

Comment: Do you set the DataContext? and do you use the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface?

Comment: try to set in the ViewModel (in the constructor) `window.DataContext = this;`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I resolved the issue in my application.

1. My Application has many solutions and each solution has many projects.
2. I am running .NET 4.5 on VS 2012 using WPF.
3. My application structure is:

   MyApplication

   - CoreSolution

     -ProjectA1

     -Resources

     -Images

     ```
       warning.ico (Build action set to Resource)
       information.ico (Build action set to Resource)
       error.ico (Build action set to Resource)
     ```

     +ProjectA2
   - PersonDatabaseSolution

     +ProjectB1

     +ProjectB2
4. I have added images (actual images and not links) in CoreSolution's ProjectA1 project. I did not change the build action of any of the images. Compiled the project to get ProjectA1.dll.
5. In ProjectB2's PersonDatabaseSolution, I refer to error.ico in code behind using the following:

   ```
       private ImageSource _myImage
       public ImageSource MyImage
       {
        get
        {
         if(_myImage==null)
         {
          uriLoc=new Uri("pack://application:,,,/CoreSolution.ProjectA1;component/Resources/Images/error.ico", UriKInd.Absolute);
          BitmapImage bmImage = new BitmapImage();
          bmImage.BeginInit();
          bmImage.UriSource = uriLoc;
          bmImage.EndInit();
          _myImage=bmImage;
         }
         return _myImage;
        }
       }
   ```
6. The MyImage property is bound in the xaml:

   ```
    <Image Source="{Binding Path=MyImage}"/>
   ```

So far this has worked for me. Hope it helps others as well.

Thanks,
RDV